# Vertical growing edittext using 9 patch background

Tags: android

My program has a messaging part. So, I designed an edittext that has a 9 patch background. My question is that I want my edittext growing only vertically. How can I do that ?
My messaging part seems like this:

**Messaging**

[image]

And it's xml:

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Write something..."
                    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:allowUndo="false"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_messaging" />`
```

"back_messaging" is a 9-patch image which seems like : 
[9-patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06PYx.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 9 patch image as you already mentioned. use `singleLine=false`

and put the left side black patch on the image to a pixel which can stretch the image without disturbing the upper portion. Like you have done in the back_messaging.